# How to convert list written in string back to list?

Tags: python, string, list, types

I have some data as string which contains list of list of data.

`data = "[['asdaddas','asdasdasd'],['asdawdasd','asdwdefe']]"`

As you can see that this is nested list in string not of type(list()).

I have tried manually using online-json-formatter and copying data from the result and pasting it for assigning it to some variable. like:

`data = [['asdaddas','asdasdasd'],['asdawdasd','asdwdefe']]`

but here is the issue that this is not how i will be doing it on all iterations. There should be some code to convert it from above mention string type data to list type data.

I hope you guys can help me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into using AST `eval()` in Python.

Comment: I would only use `eval`, if there is no other way (since it may be dangerous on untrusted input). In your example, `json.loads` suffices (needs `import json`)

Comment: You can convert it to valid json by changing ' to " and enclose at {}. After that use json.loads(text)

Comment: you're right, replacing `'` with `"` is needed, but the enclosing in `{}` is not required.

Comment: @LorenzHetterich Yeah, you're right. Checked that.

Comment: Thanks everyone it is solved. All the three solutions by you guys worked for me. Thanks a lot. @ti